# How to check which entry box the user right clicked in when using clipboard?

Tags: python, tkinter

So I have a form with 3 entry boxes.  You can right-click in 1 of the 3 entry boxes and select "copy".  This should copy the text in the particular entry box you clicked in.

Instead, text from all 3 entry boxes is copied to the clipboard.
How can I only copy text from the entry box that the user right-clicks in?

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import os
import pypyodbc
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import BOTH, END, LEFT
import tkinter as tk


class Adder(ttk.Frame):
    """The adders gui and functions."""
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.root = parent
        self.init_gui()

# Copy and Paste Buttons BEGIN Here
    def button1(self):
        self.printcopy()
        self.copy()

    def copy(self, event=None):
        self.clipboard_clear()
        text = self.first_entry.get()  # This is the method I need to work on.
        text2 = self.last_entry.get()
        text3 = self.lic_entry.get()   # All entries are copied
        self.clipboard_append(text)   
        self.clipboard_append(text2)
        self.clipboard_append(text3)

    def printcopy(self):
        print ('Copy!')

    def popup(self, event):
        self.aMenu.post(event.x_root, event.y_root)

# Copy and Paste Buttons END Here


    def init_gui(self):
        """Builds GUI."""
        self.root.title('Verify')
        self.root.option_add('*tearOff', 'FALSE')

        self.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='nsew') # this starts the entire form


        self.outline = tkinter.LabelFrame(self, height=80, width=900) # border frame
        self.outline.grid(column=0, row=1, columnspan=5, padx=5, ipady=10, pady=5)


        # Input Boxes and Button

        self.first_entry = tkinter.Entry(self, width=28) # first input box
        self.first_entry.grid(sticky='', column=1, row=1) 

        self.last_entry = tkinter.Entry(self, width=28) # second input box
        self.last_entry.grid(sticky='', column=2, row=1) 

        self.lic_entry = tkinter.Entry(self, width=28) # third input box
        self.lic_entry.grid(sticky='', column=3, row=1) 

        # Output frame for answer
        self.entries = []
        self.output0 = tkinter.Entry(self, width=149, justify='center', bd='0', bg='#E0E0E0')
        self.output0.grid(column=0, row=6, columnspan=5, padx=1)
        self.entries.append(self.output0)
        # Copy and Paste
        self.aMenu = tk.Menu(self, tearoff=0)
        self.aMenu.add_command(label='Copy', command=self.button1)
        self.first_entry.bind("<Button-3>", self.popup)
        self.last_entry.bind("<Button-3>", self.popup)
        self.lic_entry.bind("<Button-3>", self.popup)
        self.output0.bind("<Button-3>", self.popup)

        self.blank = tkinter.LabelFrame(self, height=5, bd=0,) # blank line
        self.blank.grid(row=16,)      

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    Adder(root)
    root.resizable(width=False, height=False) # locks window from being resized
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Are your trying to copy all 3 fields at once or just one at a time?

Comment: To accomplish what you want to do you can move the entry fields to a list and work with a list in a function. I will work on an example.

Comment: @SierraMountainTech Just one.  My problem is that all 3 fields are copied at the same time.  I just want to copy the one field that the user selects.

Comment: I updated my answer with a method you could use to cope the widget you are currently in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the kind of behavior you are looking for I have reworked your code accomplish what you want.

1st You should not import tkinter twice like you are doing here. Just use `import tkinter as tk` this will work fine for everything you need from tkinter.

We needed make sure the focus is on the widget you are right clicking in by using `event.widget.focus()` in the `popup` method and to get the current focus inside of your frame `self.outline` and then `get()` the value of that entry.

if you change your `copy()` method to:

```
def copy(self):
    self.clipboard_clear()
    self.clipboard_append(self.outline.focus_get().get())
```

And change your `popup()` method to:

```
def popup(self, event):
    event.widget.focus()
    self.aMenu.post(event.x_root, event.y_root)
```

It should work as you need it to.

Take a look at the below code:

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk


class Adder(ttk.Frame):
    """The adders gui and functions."""
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.root = parent
        self.root.title('Verify')
        self.root.option_add('*tearOff', 'FALSE')
        self.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='nsew')

        self.outline = tk.LabelFrame(self, height=80, width=900)
        self.outline.grid(column=0, row=1, columnspan=5, padx=5, ipady=10, pady=5)

        self.first_entry = tk.Entry(self, width=28)
        self.first_entry.grid(sticky='', column=1, row=1) 
        self.first_entry.bind("<Button-3>", self.popup)

        self.last_entry = tk.Entry(self, width=28)
        self.last_entry.grid(sticky='', column=2, row=1) 
        self.last_entry.bind("<Button-3>", self.popup)

        self.lic_entry = tk.Entry(self, width=28)
        self.lic_entry.grid(sticky='', column=3, row=1)
        self.lic_entry.bind("<Button-3>", self.popup)

        self.output0 = tk.Entry(self, width=149, justify='center', bd='0', bg='#E0E0E0')
        self.output0.grid(column=0, row=6, columnspan=5, padx=1)
        self.output0.bind("<Button-3>", self.popup)

        self.aMenu = tk.Menu(self, tearoff=0)
        self.aMenu.add_command(label='Copy', command=self.copy)

        self.blank = tk.LabelFrame(self, height=5, bd=0) # blank line
        self.blank.grid(row=16)      

    def copy(self):
        self.clipboard_clear()
        self.clipboard_append(self.outline.focus_get().get())


    def popup(self, event):
        event.widget.focus()# this moves the focus to the entry field you right click in.
        self.aMenu.post(event.x_root, event.y_root)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    Adder(root)
    root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Works.  Thank you!

Comment: There is no need to track which widget is being worked on. Tkinter can tell you which widget has focus, and the event object passed to the callback can tell you which widget got the event.

Comment: @BryanOakley Do you have a link to the documentation for this? I can then update my answer.

Comment: It's documented many places. Using `event.widget` is a very common pattern.

Comment: I would also say that your statement that init_gui is redundant is not necessarily true, except in the most broad sense. Many people like to have a separate function to initialize the GUI, so that the `__init__` method is short and tidy. You should change your statement to make it clear that your statement is a personal preference, not an absolute rule.

Comment: @BryanOakley I will keep that in mind for the future. Is it just for readability or is there another reason why one would like to do it this way?

Comment: readability, though this pattern makes it easy to completely re-render the GUI without having to recreate the class (ie: you can call the init method from more than one place)

Comment: @BryanOakley: I have updated my answer to use `focus_get()` instead of the unnecessarily long way I was doing it. As always thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @Prox Take a look at my reworked answer. It is a better option to use `focus_get()` here instead of the round about method I original posted.

Comment: Another thing.  When I remove the top "import tkinter", I get an error...   root = tkinter.Tk() NameError: name 'tkinter' is not defined

Comment: Us tk instead of tkinter for your prefixes

Comment: My program is actually much larger than what I posted above.  I use tkinter and tk in some places because one may have options that the other doesnt.  Is that normal for people to do that?

Comment: Not true. They both have the same exact options.

Comment: Oh your right.  I just adjusted everything.  So it it tk and ttk that is different?

Comment: Yes tk and ttk are different. The ttk import is for "fancy" or nicer looking widgets.

Comment: Is it normal that people mix those?

Comment: Normally You would do `import tkinter as tk` and then on the next line `from tkinter import ttk` this is normal when you need to make a tkinter GUI but you would like to use the fancy or nicer widgets like buttons and labels from the ttk import.

Comment: I'm getting something weird.  My program changes the text in the "self.output0" entry.  It puts data into a results variable and writes it with. "self.output0.insert(0,results[0])"  The copy function doesn't work once the text has been changed based upon the users action.  I'll keep playing with it.

Comment: @Prox that would seam to be a separate question than what we have already gone over. You may want to ask another question on stack overflow for this. Without seeing your current code its hard to test so this is another reason you should ask another question.

Comment: Oh wait, it works.  I was just clicking in the box and pushing copy.  With focus_get, you have to actually highlight the text you want to copy.  So your first idea would work well if someone wanted to copy all text in the entry without having to highlight it.

Comment: @Prox You do not need to highlight. focus_get only gets the widget then the use of `.get()` gets a string of the entire content of the widget. No highlighting is required or even has any effect on it.

Comment: @Prox You do however need to be inside of the widget. So the focus needs to be on the widget for the right click to work correctly. You could have the focus forced to the widget on the same right click and that should fix the problem.

Comment: @Prox I have updated my answer to fix the problem you were having. We needed to make sure the focus was set to the widget you were right clicking in.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150353/discussion-between-prox-and-sierra-mountain-tech).

Answer (score 0):

The `event` object passed to the callback has a `widget` attribute which tells you which widget received the event.

You can also ask tkinter which widget currently has the focus with the common widget method `focus_get`.